# White line on right side of iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I am beginning out with iOS development and I have been trying to get an image as the background. I set an Imageview in the back as a background image and it looks great, except for when I run it on the iPhone simulator when it leaves a thin white line on the right side of the screen. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Check your auto-layout constraints if you are implementing it on the main.storyboard or if you are doing in code make sure you center it or set boundaries on the screen. A simple google search will definitely help you out!